# Why are my Verticies/Edges/Faces locked from moving up and down?

Tags: object-mode

I'm trying to simply move any vertex/edge/face up or down but visually it does not move. I see values changing when i'm moving them but ultimately nothing occurs visually. Additionally, if I try rotating a face so that one edge goes up and the other goes down they just pinch together instead (Imgur link shows what happens when the red rotate ring is moved). I can move the entire object normally up and down outside object mode. Using Blender with Maya config (I used Maya years ago for about 3 years.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlYh4.jpg
[image]
Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: could you share your blendfile at https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5301" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5301/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scale of the object in "object mode" is set to 0. While scaling the z-axis with 0 in edit mode is great to get a flat surface, in object mode, this leads to this expected but explainable behavior.

[image: scale]

Set the scale in z-direction to 1 while in object mode and it will work again.

On another note I would be VERY CAREFUL to have an object SCALED IN OBJECT MODE, if you are trying to model a real world floor plan with REAL WORLD UNITS.

I never use scale/rotation in object mode unless I'm compositing multiple objects together.

In this case I would suggest to apply apply scale in object mode and then select all and scale in edit mode.

Comment: Ah I see, the plane as a whole outside object mode need to have a scale of 1 on the Z Axis. I can now move my said items of concern up and down. Thanks much!

Comment: Please accept and or upvote the question if it helped you. It will make it easier for other users to see what the problem was.